# Unique solution for Poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions, maximum-principle

Given the non-linear Poisson equation

$\Delta u=f(u(x,y)), \text{in } \Omega$

$u=0, \text{on } \partial \Omega$

in a bounded region $\Omega$,

show that if f is Lipschitz-continuous with a sufficiently small Lipschitz constant, then the problem only has one solution.

Well, Lipschitz continuous means that $|f(u_1(x,y))-f(u_2(x,y))| \leq L|u_1(x,y)-u_2(x,y)|$ for a constant $L>0$. How could I show that $u_1=u_2$? Do I need to use the maximum principle somehow?

Comment: It's worth to mention an example that $\Delta u + 2u = 0$ (as non linear Possion equation or linear elliptic equation ) with $u = 0 \ \text{on }\partial \Omega$  on the square $\Omega = (0,\pi)^2 \subset \Bbb{R}^2$  does not has unique solution.

Comment: the problem in the example above is that, (1) $c = 2 >0$ therefore $c\le 0$ does not holds(which needed for the maximum principle for elliptic equation), (2) the Lipschitz constant is $2$ everywhere not sufficient small.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is an application of the maximum principle, but is not immediately obvious. Suppose that $u,v\in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\overline \Omega )$ both solve the PDE and let $ w:= u -v$. If we define $c:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ by $$ \tag{$\ast$}c(x) = \begin{cases}
-\frac{f(u(x))-f(v(x))}{u(x)-v(x)}, &\text{if } u(x) \neq v(x) \\
0, &\text{if } u(x) = v(x) . 
\end{cases} $$ then, $$ \Delta w(x) = f(u(x))-f(v(x))=-c(x)w(x) \qquad \text{for all } x\in \Omega.$$ Thus, $$\begin{cases}\Delta w +cw=0 &\text{in }\Omega \\
w=0, &\text{on } \partial \Omega. \end{cases} $$ Of course the standard maximum principle still doesn't tell us anything about $w$ since it requires $c\leqslant 0$ (which we cannot guarantee). Fortunately for us, there more general maximum principles which relax the assumption that $c\leqslant 0$, but instead (usually) impose either that $\| c\|_{L^\infty (\Omega)}$ is small in some sense or $\Omega$ is small in some sense.

In this case, we can't say anything about the 'size' of $\Omega$, but, since $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $L>0$, it follows immediately from ($\ast$) that $$\| c\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leqslant L $$ and we are allowed to take $L$ as small as we like. By Corollary 3.8 in Gilbarg and Trudinger, for example, if $L$ is sufficiently small then we must have that $w=0$ in $\Omega$ which completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me what this corollary is about because I couldn't find any information online?

Comment: Are you asking me to give the statement of the corollary or explain it?

Comment: Hi @JackT  , I have a related question, does this implies that the eigenfunction of the Laplace operator is unique for each fixed $\lambda$ with a given bounded smooth domain?

Comment: Oh I asked a silly question, since eigenequation is linear equation, once it has a non zero solution it can not be unique by simply multiplying by a scale factor.  Secondly this theorem does not apply to eigen equation since the Lip constant is not arbitrary small for the Eigenequation